# Why are the changes I make in my Storyboard (Xcode) not being reflected on my app?

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

I've been working on an app recently but I ran into an annoying issue. None of the changes I've been making to my storyboard have been reflected on my iPhone (which is being used instead of the simulator).

I've already tried a lot of things such as cleaning the build folder, deleting provisioning profiles, deleting the app on my phone and rebooting it, etc. Any ideas on what else I could do to fix it, or what's causing all of this?

Thanks

(Sorry if it sounds a bit unclear, I just have a hard time describing it)

Comment: I think there will be some custom lib or any kind of control that is having a custom class like your text field or your button have custom class and it's having problem to update frames so that could be an issue and if you remove it, It will work well check your recent designed screens only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be a myriad of reasons why this could be happening, some of which can be indeterministic in nature.

I'll just list a few fixes down, although some of these you've already tried.

1. Clean and rebuild.
2. Quit xCode, delete `derived data` folder. Deploy again.
3. Delete the app from your device.
4. The storboard that you are making changes to, is not the one that is being used in the app.

I think the last one might be related to you. (or whatever changes that you are making, get overwritten by something other code in the app.)

Comment: Damn I did everything on your list except clear my derived data folder, turns out that was the solution after all! Thank you!

Comment: Glad that fixed it. :)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned answer above is correct,

***However, The main reason of occurring these issues is of cache memory. As we work and manage lots of things via xcode. Xcode manage all their stuff, so after lot of working there are some cases happened(like: internal source engine crashed for some reason) when our changes are not reflected in the form of output and the reason is made because of cache and derived data are recalled. As mentioned the steps, these will again reset and clear the cache and on working with xcode editor your work will reflected correctly.***

It will be a best practice to delete all your derived data and module cache once in a week so there will be no issue occurred during your critical workload.